# How can i create/add animated icon/image for my application to be show in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, winforms

This link shows how to make an animated icon in the tray icon :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/09/12/animation-and-text-in-system-tray-using-c.aspx

But sometimes the user can't see all the icons in the tray icon .
I want that when my program is recording while a process runs, the program will be in the TaskBar with animated icon/image .
When it stops recording, it will be back to the tray icon regular without animation.

How can i do it ?

Comment: animated taskbar icons are are really endangered species. personally i don't remember whether i have come across any. see if this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14820/Animated-System-Tray-Icon-Taskbar-Icon-and-Titleba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've supplied demonstrates what you're trying to do by the looks.

All you will need to do is listen for and catch the recording event, change the notification icon and start the animation loop. When recording stops you will do the same - change the icon back and start the loop again.

Whether or not a user can see taskbar or tray icons will depend on their personal preferences so I'm not sure this is something you'll have any control over.

If you can tell us what particular part you're getting stuck on, perhaps we can help further.

Comment: the link is about animating tray-icons. it is an analogy for what @jonek actually wants. he wants to animate taskbar icons.

Comment: timothy no what you wrote is what i needed . The only problem is that the icons in the tray are hidden at least in my windows 8 there is a small arrow face up i need to click to see all the icons . So my fear is that if someone will be in a record mode he might forget it and leave it that way . Im looking for away to signal the user somehow when he is in a recording mode .

Comment: Hi JoneK, if that's the case then no you probably won't be able to change this, can read here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/use-the-taskbar perhaps you could use the taskbar icon  instead?

Comment: Or if you want to go digging into the shell you could try something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174120/c-sharp-how-to-determine-if-hwnd-is-in-tray-icons